# Is hot code replacement available in Play?

Tags: playframework

I come from Tomcat background, it has this nice feature called "hot code replacement" - it can replace Java code in a running web application, without interfering with existing HTTP sessions/initialized objects.

Recently I started learning Play framework, although it does does "code replacement", but it seems to **restart** entire application, not just replacing changed code, therefore all Java objects/static variables/HTTP sessions are lost.

Is Tomcat's hot code replacement feature (or similar) available in Play?

Comment: Hum. Play is designed to be statelesss, without server state. Do you store yourself states on the server for your authentication?

Comment: @JulienLafont Most web programs have a login process. Using Tomcat and Java, I never had to login again to see new code taking place. Play framework seems to preserve absolutely no session information when code is reloaded.

Comment: "Play framework seems to preserve absolutely no session information when code is reloaded". Yes, the JVM is reseted when class are reloaded. And it's usually not a problem because Play is thought to be completely stateless. You can have a login process with stateless server. All is in your cookies. Do your store another data on your server, or do use only the session mechanism?

Comment: With Tomcat, my J2EE application can have any state information (be it session information, static variable, or any object) and reloaded class will not spoil any of them. Is this behaviour (or similar) available in Play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, Play is designed to be stateless so there is no need for such a feature. Store your data on the client, by using the session and it will definitely be available after reloading code. [`play.mvc.Http.Session`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Session.html)/[`play.api.mvc.Session`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Session) uses cookies secured against manipulation by a secret key.

If it's inapplicable to store your data in the session (because of its size or because it's used globally by multiple clients), use the [cache](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaCache). The trick is to make anything that you expect to be in the cache recoverable, in case it is missing for some reason (like a restart in your case).

> For any data stored in the cache, a regeneration strategy needs to be put in place in case the data goes missing. This philosophy is one of the fundamentals behind Play, and is different from Java EE, where the session is expected to retain values throughout its lifetime.

Comment: Does that mean there is not a way to preserve a static variable value during/after code replacement?

Comment: It sounds too odd to be true. If my application takes 10 minutes to start up, I should not be waiting for another 10 minutes just for Play to apply a small code change.

Comment: @HowardGuo I just don't know of any ways. There still could be some ways though - afaik Play can run in Tomcat somehow, it may be possible to use that instead of the integrated play server? Other than that, a 10 minute startups sounds strange too. If possible I would make all initialisation lazy, which plays quite well with the cache approach. Of course it could also be that Play just isn't the right tool for that architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I think *the main thing* about Play (can speak only for 1.x branch) being stateless is to avoid the usage of 'session' state in the server in any sort (http session, static variables, etc) as I think it helps to ease scalability, but you can have the 'logged in' state in an encrypted cookie in the client side (sent to the server with every http request), for authentication, I think this is enough, if you want user data, just query the database again (for simple strings store them in the session too).

Anyway, if you want to 'preserve' some global state in server side for the entire application lifetime use `@OnApplicationStop` to serialize your current state (static variables, some object here and there) and `@OnApplicationStart` to load it again, this mechanism is compatible with Play dev mode 'code replacement' :).

Something like this:

**SomeObject.java**

```
package util;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class SomeObject implements Serializable {
    public String someAttribute;
}
```

**ClassWithStaticState.java**

```
package util;

public class ClassWithStaticState {
    public static SomeObject someStateObject; 
}
```

**StatePreserver.java**

```
package util;

@OnApplicationStop
public class StatePreserver extends Job {

    @Override
    public void doJob() throws Exception {
        new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("preservedstate.bin")).writeObject(ClassWithStaticState.someStateObject);
    }
}
```

**StateLoader.java**

```
package util;

@OnApplicationStart
public class StateLoader extends Job {
    @Override
    public void doJob() throws Exception {
        File file = new File("preservedstate.bin");
        SomeObject someObject;
        if (file.exists()) {
            someObject = (SomeObject) new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)).readObject();
        } else {
            someObject = new SomeObject();
            someObject.someAttribute = "hey!"; // attribute can be modified at runtime but will be preserved across Play development modifications
        }
        ClassWithStaticState.someStateObject =  someObject;
    }
}
```

See here for some explanation on these annotations http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/jobs

Actually I think that instead of serialization, Play has the `play.cache.Cache` exactly to replace serialization in these examples.